# How to redirect the home page of the site to /public/index.html path

Tags: java, apache, redirect

I am working on dynamic web project and follwoing is my web.xml contents:

```
<display-name>WEBSITE_NAME</display-name>

      <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>/public/index.html</welcome-file>
      </welcome-file-list>
```

my problem is wen I run the project and enter the WEBSITE_NAME the index.html file contents appearing on the page but without loading the images that exist in the public/img path, if I append to the query string /public/index.html manually, the site work correctly. The question is: how can force the site to direct to the /public/index.html path when I enter its name?

Answer (score 0):

Check this rewrites in your .htaccess file (change example.com to your domain):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /public/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [L]
```

Comment: there is no .htaccess in my website. I have another websites that doing this redirect without .htaccess file. can I do this? or should I create .htaccess file?